# CircleCI reports mkdir successful, but can't find directory

Tags: ubuntu, circleci, amazon-linux

New CircleCI user here. I’ve been struggling trying to execute a `mkdir` command. Or, more accurately, to find the **results** of command execution.

The step exits successfully in my workflow, but the folder does not seem to actually exist. I'm unable to locate it anywhere in the file system.

Here's my config.yml file:

```
# PHP CircleCI 2.0 configuration file
#
# Check https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/language-php/ for more details
#
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    branches:
      only:
        - staging
    working_directory: ~/build
    docker:
      - image: circleci/php:7.2-node-browsers

    steps:
      - checkout

      - run: 
          name: APT Installs (ZIP, PDO, MySQL, Composer)
          command: |        
            sudo docker-php-ext-install zip
            sudo docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
            sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
            sudo composer self-update

      - run: 
          name: Install Python and PIP
          command: |
            sudo apt-get install -y python3.7
            sudo apt install -y python3-pip
            sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip
            sudo pip3 install --upgrade awscli
            sudo pip3 install --upgrade awsebcli

      - run:
          name: Create Image Directory (if not exists)
          command: |            
            sudo mkdir -m 0755 -p /var/user_image
            ls -l /var/user_image

      - run:
          name: Setup AWS credentials
          command: |
            mkdir ~/.aws && printf "[profile eb-cli]\naws_access_key_id = $REDACTED\naws_secret_access_key = $REDACTED" > ~/.aws/config

      - deploy:
          name: Deploy to Elastic Beanstalk
          command: |
            eb deploy PixapadTest-env

      # Download and cache dependencies
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            # "composer.lock" can be used if it is committed to the repo
            - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "composer.json" }}
            # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
            - v1-dependencies-      

      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - node-v1-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
            - node-v1-

      - run: 
          name: Install app dependencies
          command: |       
            composer install -n --prefer-dist

      - save_cache:
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "composer.json" }}
          paths:
            - ./vendor

      - run:
          name: Database Setup
          command: |
            vendor/bin/phinx migrate -e staging
```

Here's a screenshot from the most recent successful workflow:

[image]

Where am I going wrong?

**EDIT #1:** At the suggestion of a CircleCI user, I added `ls -l /var/user_image` to my config.yml just below `sudo mkdir -m 0755 -p /var/user_image`. The workflow step outputs the following:

[image]

No error, but I still can't find the directory. I suspect at this point it's being deleted by a process... I'm just not sure why.

**EDIT #2:** Updated with full config.yml.

Comment: How are you checking to see if the directory exist?

Comment: Using `sudo find /var/user_image`, `sudo find *user_image*` as well as manually opening folders and using `ll`.

Also, I added `ls -l /var/user_image` to my config.yml at the recommendation of a CircleCI user. It outputs "total 0" without error. It appears the folder is created, but possibly deleted at some point.

Comment: We need to see more of your config, or a build link, to see what's going on. I ran a simplified version of your config and it works just fine for me. https://circleci.com/gh/felicianotech/cci-testing-pub/927

Comment: Awesome! Updated. Thank you for taking a look!

Comment: Sorry but I'm still not seeing what the actual problem is. The config looks good and the screenshot you provided doesn't show the error.

Comment: Well, just after going to bed I had a revelation. I was looking for the folder on the production box, while telling CircleCI to create it in the container. DOH! I just need to figure out how to create it if it does not exist in my Elastic Beanstalk instance.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I over-complicated this **and** misunderstood the process.

My goal was to create a directory on my application server, which was hosted in Elastic Beanstalk. Although I wanted to create the directory on the server, the commands I was using in my config.yml file were creating the directory in the container. CircleCI behaved perfectly fine. I didn't!

Instead, I simply needed to add the command to the config file located in my .ebextensions source folder.

Here's the full config file from the .ebextensions folder, for anyone else who runs across this.

```
files:
    "/root/.ssh/config":
        owner: root
        group: root
        mode: "000600"
        content: |
            Host github.com
                User git
                Hostname github.com
                IdentityFile /root/.ssh/battlestardigitalbot-github-deploy
    "/root/.ssh/known_hosts":
        owner: root
        group: root
        mode: "000644"
        content: |
            [REDACTED]


commands:
    01-command:
        command: sudo aws s3 cp s3://battlestar-deployment-key/battlestardigitalbot-github-deploy /root/.ssh
    02-command:
        command: sudo chmod 600 /root/.ssh/battlestardigitalbot-github-deploy
    03-command:
        command: sudo mkdir -m 0755 -p /var/user_image
```

Special thank you to [FelicianoTech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1195276/felicianotech), whose patient questions eventually knocked some sense into my noggin!